# Switch between tabs (panels) in Mint

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts

How to switch between tabs (panels) in any window (i.e. setting windows for keyboard) in Linux Mint?

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> in Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Pg Dn/Up</kbd> work sometimes.

Comment: Briilliant! Using terminal with multiple tabs Linux Mint 21.3.  Never found a solution before; bet it would work in a lot of places that Ctrl-Tab does not.  Shift+PgUp/Dwn scrolls terminal screen by a page.  Used alone, PgUp/Dwn type a ~ (tilde).

Answer (score 1):

F6 works in Nemo in Linux Mint 19.1.

Answer (score 1):

## I used it for `MINT 19.3`

> Alt+tab

**If it not work you can try**

> Ctrl+Tab

### or

> Alt+Page Up/Down

or

> Ctrl+Pg Dn/Up

## Finally You can try it

> `F6`

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up/Down</kbd>. It would work on every Desktop Environment.

Comment: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is for windows (app) switching, not switching between tabs in a window (on every Desktop Environment).

Comment: I've misunderstood the question

Answer (score 0):

I use my mouse - hold right button and roll the wheel up/down.

From my Keyboard settings I found out that CTRL and (shift)TAB scroll right or left... and from here I tested and found that CTRL works with PgUp and PgDn too.

I love the shortcut used in Chromium (mouseover and roll wheel) and used EASYSTROKE to make it a system wide mousegesture/shortcut. Slightly improved now because I can press my right mouse button instead of moving the pointer over the tabs (less accuracy required makes for easier gestures).

Comment: OP asked for keyboard shortcut, not mouse.